# Wordpress - SoapTheme CityTours cannot random post

Tags: wordpress, templates

I've a problem when I want to custom template on WordPress, for now I use themes from SoapTheme https://themeforest.net/item/citytours-hotel-tour-booking-wordpress-theme/13181652?s_rank=2.

And now I want to custom the hotel list, I want the hotel list can order by random order, not `asc` or `desc`. I've change some code on some function but not working.

Anyone can help me? or maybe someone have use this themes can tell me how to custom this view..

Answer (score 0):

Please find a code which is responsible for listing the hotel items and change inside it the **orderby** parameter to **rand**. As I suppose it is based on usage of the WP_Query or WP_Query-based function.

If there is no **orderby** parameter - add it, as in some cases it is unnecessary due its default value - ordering by date).